# Photoshop script/plugin to modify text faster

Tags: text, plugins, photoshop-script

i have to work on some projects that require editing couple of text over and over again, so i was thinking if there Is a way to make it faster or something, knowing that these text layers are smart objects with effects, even tho the base text is a normal Black text.I know absolutely nothing abt programming or coding, so i am asking here.

Comment: If you want someone to write a script for you I believe you have better chances by hiring someone: StackOverflow isn't a code on demand service.

Comment: yes, i know. just wanted to know if it's possibile the way i Imagine it, with some explanations. i will look forward to hire someone

Comment: Seems to be possible